# How do I find the column index of an element in a 2-D array in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a 2D array, but can I find the column index of a certain element stored in an array?
Suppose the element I was looking for is stored in row 2, but I don't know its column index. But how do I find the column index?

For example, I have a 2D array and a list of elements such as,

```
L = (A B C)
```

and I know "A" is stored in a row 2 in an array, and now I want to find the column index for "A" in an array, so I tried

```
(eval (first L))
```

but the error message was given

```
The variable A is unbound.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `EVAL` for this?  It has nothing to do with what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

This should work (for an array called `*a*`):

```
(position 'a
          (make-array (array-dimension *a* 1)
                      :displaced-to *a*
                      :displaced-index-offset (array-row-major-index *a* 2 0)))
```

A displaced array is like an alternate view into an existing array. This codes creates a displaced array that's a vector looking at the second row of the array, and then uses `position` to find the index of an element within that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any built-in function can do this.  Try something like this:

```
(defun column-position (array row item &key (test #'eql))
  (loop for i below (array-dimension array 1)
        when (funcall test (aref array row i) item)
        do (return i)))
```